# React, How to prevent execution of click event after drag?

Tags: reactjs, onclick, drag-and-drop, draggable

I have Draggable element and inside of it, I have a component with onClick event. At the end of the drag, the click event is triggered.
My draggable element looks like this. I used a package called [react-draggable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-draggable).

```
<Draggable
    position={this.state.realPosition}
    onStart={this.handleStart}
    onDrag={this.handleDrag}
    onStop={this.handleStop}
    disabled={this.state.isDialogOpen}
    bounds="parent">
      <div style={{"width":"fit-content"}}>
        <Helmet getDialogStatus={this.handleClick} />  
      </div>
</Draggable>
```

I have onClick event inside of the Helmet component which opens a dialog box. When I drag and release the element, this dialog opens. My question is how to prevent this action and how to seperate these to event?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd set a state in the Component holding `Draggable`, `isDragging` and pass it to Helmet component.

If isDragging then disable any click event.

Comment: I solved the problem with your idea. As you said I sent it via props and if the drag was done I disabled the click event. After that, in the this.handleStop function, I set 100ms timeout and enable click event again. This works for me. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Nice @İbrahimAkar  glad to hear it helped :)

Answer (score 4):

```
const [isDragging, setIsDragging] = useState<any>(false);

const eventControl = (event: { type: any; }, info: any) => {


    if (event.type === 'mousemove' || event.type === 'touchmove') {
      setIsDragging(true)
    }

    if (event.type === 'mouseup' || event.type === 'touchend') {
      setTimeout(() => {
        setIsDragging(false);
      }, 100);

    }
  }
```

and then ,

```
<Draggable
    bounds="parent"
    onDrag={eventControl}
    onStop={eventControl}
> ...
```

Comment: this answer solved my problem, but I needed to include 'touchmove' and 'touchend' events for mobile browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use  `event.stopPropagation();` in the `this.handleDrag` and `this.handleStop` event handlers by using event object. They may solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Create a ref to keep track of mouse pointer's x and y postion. If the position has changed by a certain threshold then we can consider that the mouse is being dragging, else it's a click.

```
const pointer = useRef({x: 0, y: 0});

const onMouseDown = (e) => {
    pointer.current = {x: e.clientX, y: e.clientY};
}

const onMouseUp = (e) => {
    const {x, y} = pointer.current;
    if (Math.abs(e.clientX - x) < 10 && Math.abs(e.clientY - y) < 10) {
        // your click function here
    }
}
```

and then add onMouseDown and onMouseUp events on the specific div

```
<div onMouseDown={onMouseDown} onMouseUp={onMouseUp}>{...}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can differentiate between a drag and a click by using a state variable isDragging to keep track of whether the component is being dragged or not. Use the onDrag and onStop events of the react-draggable component to manage this state. Here's an approach that works, thanks to [@lakjeewaWijebandara](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11139649/lakjeewa-wijebandara)

```
const [isDragging, setIsDragging] = useState(false);

const eventControl = (event) => {
   if (event.type === "mousemove" || event.type === "touchmove") {
     setIsDragging(true);
   }

   if (event.type === "mouseup" || event.type === "touchend") {
     setTimeout(() => {
       setIsDragging(false);
     }, 100);
   }
 };

return (
   <Draggable bounds="parent" onDrag={eventControl} onStop={eventControl}>
     <div
        onClick={() => !isDragging && handleOpen()}
        onTouchEnd={() => !isDragging && handleOpen()}
     >
       // Button content here ...
     </div>
   </Draggable>
);
```

In this solution, when a mousemove or touchmove event is detected, isDragging is set to true, indicating a drag operation. When a mouseup or touchend event is detected, isDragging is set to false after a small delay, indicating that the drag operation has ended. When the button is clicked or touched, the handleOpen function is only called if isDragging is false, ensuring it doesn't fire during a drag operation.